# How to disable a specific (faulty) laptop webcam in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, webcam

I'm using Ubuntu on my laptop, which has an embedded webcam. After it broke (dark image, connect/disconnect way too often) I replaced it with an external one which is working fine.

The old webcam, though, keeps connecting and disconnecting, and I'm getting desktop notifications non-stop and it's super annoying.

I have no way to stop the notifications (they come from a program I have to use for work and its developers won't help)

I've read about disabling the webcam kernel module but that will keep me from using the external webcam, which I require for work.Is there a way to stop the notifications at a hardware level?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can use a udev rule to disable only the internal webcam? Try [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63199/how-to-disable-usb-devices-based-on-vendor-id-in-linux-environment).

Comment: Check this thread http://askubuntu.com/questions/458515/how-to-disable-internal-webcam whether this helps in disabling the internal webcam.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to act physically on the onboard webcam to disable it: the following  command disables it,

```
      echo 0 > /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1.3/bConfigurationValue
```

but in this command the part `1-1.3` is the correct bus coordinate for the onboard webcam in my system. All we have to do is to find out the equivalent of `1-1.3` for **your** system.

First let's identify the Bus coordinates: on my system

```
      # lsusb -t 
      ...............
      :  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/3p, 480M                                                                                                                                                                                                             
         |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
         |__ Port 2: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M                                                                                                                                                                                                             
         |__ Port 2: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M                                                                                                                                                                                                             
         |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M                                                                                                                                                                                                            
         |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
```

there is only one device identified as **Class=Video**; the identification as the onboard webcam is further strengthened by the driver being uvcvideo. This has address Bus=1, Device=3, Function=0,1.

Now let us go to:

```
        # cd /sys/bus/usb/devices/; ls 
        1-0:1.0  1-1:1.0  1-1.2:1.0  1-1.3      1-1.3:1.1  2-1      2-1.5      2-1.6      2-1.6:1.1   2-1.6:1.2  2-1.6:1.4  2-1.6:1.6  2-1.6:1.8  3-0:1.0  3-2:1.0  3-3:1.0  3-3:1.2  usb1  usb3                                                                                       
        1-1      1-1.2    1-1.2:1.1  1-1.3:1.0  2-0:1.0    2-1:1.0  2-1.5:1.0  2-1.6:1.0  2-1.6:1.10  2-1.6:1.3  2-1.6:1.5  2-1.6:1.7  2-1.6:1.9  3-2      3-3      3-3:1.1  4-0:1.0  usb2  usb4
```

You can see from this I have two Bus Domains, 1 and 2; only Bus Domain 1, however, has a Bus=1,Device=3 address, so we go to:

```
      # cd 1-1.3
```

You can double-check that this is your onboard camera by comparing the content of two files,

```
      # cat id{Vendor,Product}
       1bcf
       288e
```

which you can compare with the output of

```
      # lsusb 
      ................
      Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1bcf:288e Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc.
```

which you can easily confirm, by googling to be a cam (my cam!).

In order to disable it, as sudo,

```
       # echo 0 > bConfigurationValue
```

Running `cheese` will now confirm that the webcam is disabled. To make  this permanent, include the line

```
        echo 0 > /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1.3/bConfigurationValue
```

into the file `/etc/rc.local`.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, and also very educational. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Unfortunately, over time this did not fix my problem. I still have connect/disconnect notifications all the time. Bummer

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04, I did not find an `id{Vendor,Product}` file but instead found the vendor and product info within the `uevent` file

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may help, especially if the camera location changes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

CAMERA_NAME="Integrated_Webcam_HD"

for device in $(ls /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/product); do
   if [[ $(cat "$device") =~ ${CAMERA_NAME} ]]; then
     echo "Found $(cat "${device}") @ $device"
     if [[ ${device} =~ \/([a-z\.0-9\-]+)\/product ]]; then
       echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind
     fi
   fi
done
```